# How to use JQuery prettyDate plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please I will like to know, how do I use or invoke John Resig pretty date js script? I have tried both his and the plugin version hosted on [Google code](http://code.google.com/p/jqueryjs/source/browse/trunk/plugins/prettydate/jquery.prettydate.js?r=6366)

Below is the code I have tried:

```
// HTML
<div id="block-menu-menu-tour">
    Hello
    <a title="2008-01-28T20:24:17Z"></a>
</div>

// With JQuery
window.alert($("a").prettyDate());

// plain DOM
function prettyLinks(){
  var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
  for ( var i = 0; i < links.length; i++ )
    if ( links[i].title ) {
      var date = prettyDate(links[i].title);
      if ( date )
        links[i].innerHTML = date;
    }
}
prettyLinks();
setInterval(prettyLinks, 500);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was saying undefined because the passed date is 2008, hence undefined. I changed it 
to 2011-07-24T19:18:357Z and I called the function like this: `prettyDate([UTC-date]);`

```
// With JQuery
$(function() {
$("a").prettyDate();
    });
```

I will like to advise that using JR's pretty.js is more flexible than using the jquery plugin.

For those who need it, I parsed Twitter json created_at like this:

```
/**
 * Converts to UTC date then prettyDate it.
 * 
 * Z = UTC time (To express the time of day in UTC)
 * T = local time (time of day in basic format)
 * 
 * @param holds Twitter date format of Sun, 24 Jul 2011 15:43:36 +0000
 */
liveTweets.parseDate = function(created_at) {
    //twitter_regex_date = /(\w+[,])\s(\d{2})\s(\w+)\s(\d{4})\s(\d{2}[:]\d{2}[:]\d{2})\s([+]\d{4})/;
    var months = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','Jun','Jul','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec'];
    var pattern = /\s/;
    created_at = created_at.split(pattern);
    for (i = 0, len = created_at.length; i < len; i++){
        day_of_week = created_at[0];
        day = created_at[1];
        month_pos = created_at[2];
        month = 0 + months.indexOf(month_pos) + 1; // add 1 because array starts from zero
        year = created_at[3];
        time = created_at[4];
    }
    created_at = year+'-'+month+'-'+day+'T'+time+'Z'; //2011-07-24T19:18:357Z
    created_at = prettyDate(created_at);

    if(created_at != undefined)
    return created_at;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you included both, jquery and prettyDate scripts into that document? also, have surrounded your `jQuery` code in `.ready()` block?

```
$(document).ready(function() {});
```

Comment: yes I have. The required code is getting called, but it is returning undefined. Both versions.

Comment: Both `alert($("a").prettyDate())` and when I call `prettyLinks`

Comment: `alert($("a").prettyDate());` returns `object Object`. First and foremost I don't know how the plugin says usage should have a selector `$("a")` when the actual value is in `$("a:title")`. But that still did not work when I tried it.